# Matlab, How to get each column in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I got a 4-by-n matrix, like

A =

```
 1     5     9
 3     0     6
 2     3    10
 7     8     4
```

What I want to do with A is getting each half column of A as

Line1Point1 = [1 3]

Line1Point2 = [2 7]

Line2Point1 = [5 0]

Line2Point2 = [3 8]

Line3Point1 = [9 6]

Line3Point2 = [10 4]

How could I do that? I’m pretty new to matlab coding.. Any help is really appreciated..

Cheers

Comment: This either calls for a matrix (as two of the current answers suggest), or for a cell array (as one other answer suggests). Just don't make a bunch of named variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use reshape function, for example:

```
>> A =  [1     5     9;
 3     0     6;
 2     3    10;
 7     8     4];
>> reshape(A,2,6)
ans =

     1     2     5     3     9    10
     3     7     0     8     6     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Storing such information as many variables is generally a **bad** idea

Some options for storing and accessing are

### Cell array

```
Line=mat2cell(A,[2,2],ones(1,size(A,2))).'
```

access with

```
Line{2,1}
ans =

     5
     0
```

### Indexing

as other answers

### Anonymous Function

```
Line=@(l,p)A(2*p-1:2*p,l)
```

access with

```
Line(2,1)

ans =

     5
     0
```

### Structure

Not really a useful solution, more for interests sake

```
for ii=1:size(A,2);for jj=1:2;Line(ii).Point(jj).Value=A(2*jj-1:2*jj,ii);end;end
```

access with

```
Line(2).Point(1).Value

ans =

     5
     0
```

Answer (score 1):

**A(1:2,1)** will give you first half of the first column.

**A(3:4,1)** will give you second half of the first column.

**A(1:2,2)** will give you first half of the second column.

**A(3:4,2)** will give you second half of the second column.

**A(1:2,3)** will give you first half of the third column.

**A(3:4,3)** will give you second half of the third column.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using 3D arrays to store and then access those values.

**Code**

```
N = size(A,1)/2;
LinePoint = permute(reshape(A,N,size(A,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2])
```

Here,

- `2nd dimension indices (columns)` would represent `Line IDs`
- `3rd dimension indices` would represent `Point IDs`.

Thus, the representative 3D array would be - `LinePoint(:,LineID,PointID)`.

**Example run**

For your given `A`, we would have `LinePoint` as -

```
LinePoint(:,:,1) =
     1     5     9
     3     0     6
LinePoint(:,:,2) =
     2     3    10
     7     8     4
```

Thus,

```
Line1Point1 would be denoted by LinePoint(:,1,1)
Line1Point2 would be denoted by LinePoint(:,1,2)

Line2Point1 would be denoted by LinePoint(:,2,1)
Line2Point2 would be denoted by LinePoint(:,2,2)

Line3Point1 would be denoted by LinePoint(:,3,1)
Line3Point2 would be denoted by LinePoint(:,3,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the variables with the eval function, which executes the input string. Using eval is commonly regarded as bad practice since it is horrible to debug. 
Nevertheless, here's the code:

```
A = [1 5 9; 3 0 6; 2 3 10; 7 8 4];
for ii = 1:length(A(1,:))
    eval(['Line' num2str(ii) 'Point1 = A(1:2, ii)' ]); 
    eval(['Line' num2str(ii) 'Point2 = A(3:4, ii)' ]);
end
% Now all variables are created - for example: Line2Point1
```

A more elegant solution could be to store the vectors in a cell array. You can acces the first vectors for example by typing: c{1,1}

```
c = cell(length(A(1,:)),2)
for ii = 1:length(A(1,:))
    c{ii,1} = A(1:2, ii);
    c{ii,2} = A(3:4, ii);
end
```